# Read TeamSpeak 3 Messages with java

Tags: java, lua, chat, bots, teamspeak

im wondering if there is any other way to read out the TeamSpeak Channel Chat with java.

I know that you could use a lua plugin which opens tha java program with the messages as parameter.

The code for the Lua Plugin's event.lua file: (could be outdated)

```
local function onTextMessageEvent(serverConnectionHandlerID, targetMode, toID, fromID, fromName, fromUniqueIdentifier, message, ffIgnored)
    print("Testmodule: onTextMessageEvent: " .. serverConnectionHandlerID .. " " .. targetMode .. " " .. toID .. " " .. fromID .. " " .. fromName .. " " .. fromUniqueIdentifier .. " " .. message .. " " .. ffIgnored)
    if targetMode == 2 then
        os.execute("Program.exe " .. '"' .. message .. '"')
        if message == "!command#1" or message == "!command#2" or message == "!command#3" then
            folder = os.getenv("APPDATA")
            file = io.open(folder .. "/" .. "tmp.txt", "r")
            tempfile = file:read("*all")
            file:close()
            os.remove(folder .. "/" .. "tmp.txt")
            ts3.requestSendChannelTextMsg(serverConnectionHandlerID, tempfile, fromID)
        end
    end
    return 0
end
```

Basicly the Program.exe creates the tmp.txt file and writes the specified (inside the Program.exe) answer to the file which is sent to the chat by the lua plugin.

Now i want to know if there is any way to get the messages directly with java (so that the lua plugin isn't needed anymore)

I'm thankful for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you can simply scan the channel & server chatlogs for new entrys.
The Logs can be found here:

```
%APPDATA%\Roaming\TS3Client\chats\<UniqueServerID>
```

Unfortunately i have no idea how the UniqueServerID is generated and where the private chatlogs can be found.